# Hide some annotations

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I recently switched to OpenAPI Specifications 3 for our API documentation and the swagger annotations are huge comparing to business source code. Is there a way to hide them configurable with a button toggle ?

Comment: You can write a plugin that will fold such annotations by default, using the FoldingBuilderEx API. See here for an example: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/folding_builder.html

Comment: Thanks, will try it